# Dynamic page being empty when accessing directly or after refresh in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Whenever I try to access /contact/product it works perfectly fine. But when I try to access it directly or I refresh whilst I'm on the page the page just becomes empty.

A weird thing though is that it works perfectly fine when in the development build but in production it doesn't work.

My routing:

```
<Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Nav></Nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/contact/:product" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/privacy-policy" element={<Privacy />} />
        <Route path="/cookie-policy" element={<Cookies />} />
        <Route path="/pricing" element={<Pricing />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </Router>
```

The contact component:

```
import React from "react";
import ContactForm from "../components/Contact/ContactForm";
import "../style/Contact/Contact.scss"
import "../style/Contact/Breakpoints.scss"
import useDocumentTitle from "../lib/useDocumentTitle";

function Contact() {
  useDocumentTitle("Contact")
  return (
    <div id="contact">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="contact--left left">
            <h1 className="contact--title title">
              Let&#x2019;s build something great together
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="contact--right right">
            <ContactForm />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Contact;
```

I've tried making /product go to another component but it still doesnt work.

I'm getting these errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at main.65613560.js:1:1)
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

Comment: Check the console log if there are any errors.

Comment: Can you share the console error?

Comment: I've edited the post to now include the errors

Comment: How are you running/serving your production app? The basic gist is that the server or hosting service needs to be configured to return your root index.html file for all page requests into the app. This isn't a client-side issue, it needs to be resolved in the "back end". See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a general sense what different server environments need (*each can be wildly different*).